How to iterate a node-list in order to assign index-specific event-handlers to each element-node?
I'm trying to use a for loop to increment through multiple button elements so I can assign different actions to them.
I cannot figure this out, Here is the code.
I am very much new to javascript and I've read through MDN docs and haven't come up with anything.


let numberOfbuttons = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers");

for (i = 0; i < numberOfbuttons; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".numbers")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "1"
  })
};
body {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.Calc {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-area: 2/2;
}

button[value="0"] {
  grid-area: 5/2/5/2;
}

button {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  color: black;
}

button[value="AC"] {
  grid-area: 5/1;
}

button[value="+"] {
  grid-area: 3/4;
}

button[value="-"] {
  grid-area: 2/4;
}

.result {
  grid-area: 1/1/1/5;
  background-color: #CBD2A4;
  text-align: center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Calc">
    <div class="result">
      <p>Type in your "numbers"</p>
    </div>

    <button class="numbers">1</button>
    <button class="numbers">2</button>
    <button class="numbers">3</button>
    <button class="numbers">4</button>
    <button class="numbers">5</button>
    <button class="numbers">6</button>
    <button class="numbers">7</button>
    <button class="numbers">8</button>
    <button class="numbers">9</button>
    <button class="numbers">0</button>
    <button value="AC">AC</button>
    <button value="+">+</button>
    <button value="-">-</button>
    <button value="*">x</button>
    <button value="/">/</button>
    <button value="=">=</button>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>




you probably mean let numberOfbuttons = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers").length;

@Jawad ... are you aware that querySelectorAll returns a non-live NodeList which has its own forEach method for iterating each of it element nodes? But anyhow one never would register an event-listener for each element node, each with its customized handler function, determined by the element's index. One rather would slightly improve the HTML-structure by grouping all numbers and make use of event-delegation.

Is the OP aware of the fact that querySelectorAll actually returns a non-live NodeList which has its own forEach method for iterating each of its element nodes?
But one anyhow would never register an event-listener for each element node, each with its customized handler-function, determined by the element's index.
One rather would slightly improve the HTML-structure by grouping all the dials and make use of event-delegation.
Thus one implements a single function which handles every dial-button click-event. This handler then gets registered once at the closest parent element of all dial-buttons.


function handleCalculatorDialClick(evt) {

  const target = evt.target.closest('button');
  const { value } = target;

  const isSingleDigitDial = (/\d/).test(value);

  if (isSingleDigitDial) {
    target

      .closest('.calculator')
      .querySelector('output')
      .value = value;

  } /* else if () {

    // handle another dial

  }*/
}
document
  .querySelector('.calculator .dials')
  ?.addEventListener('click', handleCalculatorDialClick);
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.calculator {

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  width: 45%;

  button {
    color: black;
    background-color: #fffaf0;

    &:focus {
      z-index: 1;
      outline: 2px solid lime;
    }
  }

  .display {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 4;

    background-color: #CBD2A4;
    padding: .95em;
    text-align:center;
  }

  .dials {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 5 / 4;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);

    .non-zero-digits {
      grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 4;

      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

      button {
        background-color: aliceblue;
      }
    }
    .linear {
      grid-area: 1 / 4 / 3 / 4;

      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
      grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    }
    .geometric {
      grid-area: 4 / 2 / 4 / 4;

      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
    button[value="0"] {
      grid-area: 3 / 4;

      background-color: aliceblue;
    }
    button[value="="] {
      grid-area: 4 / 4;

      background-color: #ffebc5;
    }
    button[value="AC"] {
      grid-area: 4 / 1;

      background-color: #ffd88c;
    }
  } 
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="calculator">
  <output class="display">
   Type in your "numbers"
  </output>

  <div class="dials">
    <div class="non-zero-digits">
      <button value="1">1</button>
      <button value="2">2</button>
      <button value="3">3</button>
      <button value="4">4</button>
      <button value="5">5</button>
      <button value="6">6</button>
      <button value="7">7</button>
      <button value="8">8</button>
      <button value="9">9</button>
    </div>
    <button value="0">0</button>

    <div class="linear">
      <button value="+">+</button>
      <button value="-">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="geometric">
      <button value="*">x</button>
      <button value="/">/</button>
    </div>

    <button value="=">=</button>
    <button value="AC">AC</button>  
  </div>
</div>




You're almost there. querySelector returns a list, not its length. You can try this:


let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers");

for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML= "1"
  })
};
body {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
.Calc{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-area: 2/2;
}
button[value="0"]{
    grid-area: 5/2/5/2;
}
button{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    color: black;
}
button[value="AC"]{
    grid-area:5/1;
}
button[value="+"]{
    grid-area: 3/4;
}
button[value="-"]{
    grid-area: 2/4;
}
.result{
    grid-area: 1/1/1/5;
    background-color: #CBD2A4;
    text-align:center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="Calc">
      <div class="result"><p>Type in your "numbers"</p></div>

      <button class="numbers" >1</button>
      <button class="numbers" >2</button>
      <button class="numbers" >3</button>
      <button class="numbers" >4</button>
      <button class="numbers" >5</button>
      <button class="numbers" >6</button>
      <button class="numbers" >7</button>
      <button class="numbers" >8</button>
      <button class="numbers" >9</button>
      <button class="numbers" >0</button>
      <button value="AC">AC</button>
      <button value="+">+</button>
      <button value="-">-</button>
      <button value="*">x</button>
      <button value="/">/</button>
      <button value="=">=</button>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>



N.B. This is the most simple, immediate answer to the given issue, adapted to the context:

I am very much new to javascript.

For the better, more general solution, but which changes the OP's approach entirely, see @Peter Seliger's answer.

Such a stupid oversight on my part, I appreciate your feedback, I'll get on with my project and if I have any hiccups I'll post them here if I can't figure them out again

And how does this solve the OP's actual problem which is registering a specific handler-function for each numeric dial-button which writes the button's index / value / ordinal number into the result display? Your approach doe not. It always renders 1.

@PeterSeliger it has been edited out, but the OP's OP stated: "I expected it to replaced (sic) the "p" element with "1" no matter which button of the 10 were pressed."

@Jawad ... You're right. This sentence was edited out 12 hours ago, thus resulting in lost context. Now the questions are, why does the OP expect this result and what at all is the loop yet even good for?

@PeterSeliger Yes I'm not sure why it was edited out... Anyway, my guess is that OP just tried to simplify the problem since it wasn't working for them, and that their intention was to later replace 1 with i.

@PeterSeliger I've read up on event delegation and thank you for that, I'm following a course and while this calculator wasn't in the course I wasn't sure what else to do except for incrementing and choosing the buttons via array, the "Replace p with 1" part was just for testing and simplifying my problem. Thanks for the wisdom! :D

@Jawad ... In case the so far provided answers were of any help, you're strongly encouraged to pick the one, you did benefit most from and mark it as the accepted one.

I see a couple of issues with the JavaScript part of the code. Let's walk through them and correct them:

document.querySelectorAll(".numbers") returns a NodeList, but in your for loop, you're using numberOfbuttons directly, which will result in an error because you can't iterate over a NodeList like an integer. Instead, you need to get the length of the NodeList.
The grid-area for the button[value="0"] is incorrect (grid-area: 5/2/5/2;). The grid-area property should be written as four values representing the start-row, start-column, end-row, and end-column, but the values you used are duplicated. If this was intended to position the button, it might need adjusting.
You are statically setting the result to "1" for all buttons. You might want to dynamically set the result to the button's value when clicked.

let numberOfButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers");

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfButtons.length; i++) {
  numberOfButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = this.innerHTML; // Update result with clicked button's value
  });
}


